# How do I make a list of links clickable in selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I have code which finds all the links in a website, but I need to store these links in a way that allows me to used Selenium to click on specific links during the time the I am running Selenium.

This is my code, and what I expected was for Selenium to go to the particular site when I use the click() function.
What am I doing wrong!

```
import selenium
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


url = "https://www.python.org"

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(url)
driver.minimize_window()

links = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//a")))

for link in links:
    href = link.get_attribute("href")
    if href is not None:
        print(href)
#
# go to link 0
#
link(0).click


driver.quit()
```

And this is the error that is generated

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/media/joe-2/Ubuntu-Storage1/Exuma-Snoops/RGD-code/link-test-2.py", line 25, in <module>
    link(0).click
TypeError: 'WebElement' object is not callable
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is incorrect:

```
link(0).click
```

Correct way to get the first index of list and clicking it is as below:

```
links[0].click()
```

**UPDATE:** `links[0].click()` this will just click on the located element, it won't launch the href's URL on the browser.

To launch the URL extracted from href, use the below code:

```
driver.get(links[0].get_attribute("href"))
```

Comment: I did this and I didn't get any errors but the page didn't open.

Comment: Where this is going is that I will have a list of links that I click to download files that mach specific names.

Comment: Iterate through the list and use a if condition to check the matching names, if match found, click it.

Comment: The problem is that clicking on a value like link[0].click() doesn't open a new window.
All the links are printed out correctly and can be opened by right clicking on the mouse and choosing open link.
But the actual function doesn't open a window automaticlly

Comment: Just to let you know, I am running this from a terminal window.
When I added the code 

for link in links:
    href = link.get_attribute("href")
    if href is not None:
       print(href)
 
#
driver.get(links[10].get_attribute("href"))

Nothing happens, is there something else that I need to do?
Thanks

Comment: Problem solved!
The window did open but just not on the screen directly.  A new window containing the href document was there; hiding in the Chrome launch icon.

You are great, thanks for yor help.
I will be comming back with more questions though.

Take care and have a great day.